# Error : not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

I'm trying to solve this problem without success:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : 

ma.px.management.repository.service.bo.HtitrePortf.compteTitreCode; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: 
not-null property references a null or transient value : ma.px.management.repository.service.bo.HtitrePortf.compteTitreCod at ma.px.management.repository.service.dao.TitrePortfTest.testDelete(TitrePortfTest.java:47)

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : ma.px.management.repository.service.bo.HtitrePortf.compteTitreCode
    at ma.px.management.repository.service.dao.TitrePortfTest.testDelete(TitrePortfTest.java:47)
```

This is the code of `HtitrePortf` class:

```
package ma.px.management.repository.service.bo;
import java.io.Serializable

;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author imTech
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "rtitre")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rtitre.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Rtitre r")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Rtitre.findByCode", query = "SELECT r FROM Rtitre r WHERE r.code = :code")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Rtitre.findByCodeISIN", query = "SELECT r FROM Rtitre r WHERE r.codeISIN = :codeISIN")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Rtitre.findByNom", query = "SELECT r FROM Rtitre r WHERE r.nom = :nom")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Rtitre.findByClasse", query = "SELECT r FROM Rtitre r WHERE r.classe = :classe")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Rtitre.findByCategorie", query = "SELECT r FROM Rtitre r WHERE r.categorie = :categorie")})
public class Rtitre implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "codeISIN")
    private String codeISIN;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "classe")
    private String classe;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "categorie")
    private String categorie;

    public Rtitre() {
    }

    public Rtitre(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Rtitre(String code, String codeISIN) {
        this.code = code;
        this.codeISIN = codeISIN;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCodeISIN() {
        return codeISIN;
    }

    public void setCodeISIN(String codeISIN) {
        this.codeISIN = codeISIN;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getClasse() {
        return classe;
    }

    public void setClasse(String classe) {
        this.classe = classe;
    }

    public String getCategorie() {
        return categorie;
    }

    public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
        this.categorie = categorie;
    }




    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (code != null ? code.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Rtitre)) {
            return false;
        }
        Rtitre other = (Rtitre) object;
        if ((this.code == null && other.code != null) || (this.code != null && !this.code.equals(other.code))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ma.px.management.repository.service.bo.Rtitre[ code=" + code + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post the code which causes this error, it means the domain class, etc, which you consider is causing this error.

Comment: Usually this means you've mapped a foreign key to a nullable column. But as @lealceldeiro mentioned, without the code we cant help very much.

Comment: amina.Oz I edited the question, and added the code of `HtitrePortf` class, which was posted as answer by you (and which is not). If you are new here, you can check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) if you have any doubt.

Comment: ok thank@lealceldeiro,  @Stephan I have  foreign key but is not null

Comment: Do you have entries in your DB that have null values for `code` or `codeISIN`? Does you db schema also state that those two columns are not nullable?